# Forecast multiple steps with LSTM

Tags: python, lstm, forecasting

Trying to build simple LSTM model to predict electricity consumption for next 24 hours. Current model predict one step ahead (1hour) and would like to improve it to forecast 24 steps ahead.

Added more code to see data shape. Tried to find solution by an example of this [post](https://github.com/danmoller/TestRepo/blob/master/TestBookLSTM.ipynb) but unsuccessfully yet. CSV file have two columns,1 - date, 2 - hourly consumption.

```
# define a function to convert a vector of time series into a 2D matrix
def convertSeriesToMatrix(vectorSeries, sequence_length):
matrix=[]
for i in range(len(vectorSeries)-sequence_length+1):
    matrix.append(vectorSeries[i:i+sequence_length])
return matrix

# random seed
np.random.seed(1234)

# load raw data
df_raw = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\vytlksn\Documents\Python_C\Electric-Power-    Hourly-Load-Forecasting-using-Recurrent-Neural-Networks-master\Sadales data comma 3.csv''', header=None)
# numpy array
df_raw_array = df_raw.values
# daily load
list_daily_load = [df_raw_array[i,:] for i in range(0, len(df_raw)) if i % 24 == 0]
# hourly load (23 loads for each day)
list_hourly_load = [df_raw_array[i,1]/1 for i in range(0, len(df_raw)) if i % 24 != 0]
# the length of the sequnce for predicting the future value
sequence_length = 24

# convert the vector to a 2D matrix
matrix_load = convertSeriesToMatrix(list_hourly_load, sequence_length)

# shift all data by mean
matrix_load = np.array(matrix_load)
shifted_value = matrix_load.mean()
matrix_load -= shifted_value
print ("Data  shape: ", matrix_load.shape)

# split dataset: 90% for training and 10% for testing
train_row = int(round(0.8 * matrix_load.shape[0]))
train_set = matrix_load[:train_row, :]

# shuffle the training set (but do not shuffle the test set)
np.random.shuffle(train_set)
# the training set
X_train = train_set[:, :-1]
# the last column is the true value to compute the mean-squared-error loss
y_train = train_set[:, -1] 
# the test set
X_test = matrix_load[train_row:, :-1]
y_test = matrix_load[train_row:, -1]

# the input to LSTM layer needs to have the shape of (number of samples, the dimension of each element)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

# build the model
model = Sequential()
# layer 1: LSTM
model.add(LSTM( input_dim=1, output_dim=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# layer 2: LSTM
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=100, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# layer 3: dense
# linear activation: a(x) = x
model.add(Dense(output_dim=1, activation='linear'))
# compile the model
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")

# train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=24, nb_epoch=25, validation_split=0.05, verbose=1)

# evaluate the result
test_mse = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print ('\nThe mean squared error (MSE) on the test data set is %.3f over %d test samples.' % (test_mse, len(y_test)))

# get the predicted values
predicted_values = model.predict(X_test)
num_test_samples = len(predicted_values)
predicted_values = np.reshape(predicted_values, (num_test_samples,1))
```

Comment: Can you provide the shape of X_train and Y_train? The answer depends on that.

Comment: Added more explanation, thanks.